# how mapping works in solidity, and is mapping analogous to another concept in other popular languages

Tags: mapping, blockchain, ethereum, solidity

Can anyone explain how `mapping` works and why exactly it is used? Like an array is a collection of items. I have no experience in solidity, I'm just starting. I found this code on the solidity official documentation page.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

Contract CrowdFunding {
// Defines a new type with two fields.
struct Funder {
    address addr;
    uint amount;
}

struct Campaign {
    address beneficiary;
    uint fundingGoal;
    uint numFunders;
    uint amount;
    mapping (uint => Funder) funders;
}

uint numCampaigns;
mapping (uint => Campaign) campaigns;

function newCampaign(address beneficiary, uint goal) returns (uint campaignID) {
    campaignID = numCampaigns++; // campaignID is return variable
    // Creates new struct and saves in storage. We leave out the mapping type.
    campaigns[campaignID] = Campaign(beneficiary, goal, 0, 0);
}

function contribute(uint campaignID) payable {
    Campaign storage c = campaigns[campaignID];
    // Creates a new temporary memory struct, initialised with the given values
    // and copies it over to storage.
    // Note that you can also use Funder(msg.sender, msg.value) to initialise.
    c.funders[c.numFunders++] = Funder({addr: msg.sender, amount: msg.value});
    c.amount += msg.value;
}

function checkGoalReached(uint campaignID) returns (bool reached) {
    Campaign storage c = campaigns[campaignID];
    if (c.amount < c.fundingGoal)
        return false;
    uint amount = c.amount;
    c.amount = 0;
    c.beneficiary.transfer(amount);
    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, mapping is equivalent to a dictionary or a map in other programming languages. It's key-to-value storage.

In a standard array it's an index look-up e.g. if there are 10 elements in the array the indexes are 0 - 9 and it would look like this as an array of integers:

```
[0] 555
[1] 123
...
[8] 22
[9] 5
```

Or in code:

```
uint[] _ints;

function getter(uint _idx) returns(uint) {
    return _ints[_idx];
}
```

All the keys have sequential order based off the order they were added to the array.

Mapping works slightly different and the easiest way to describe it is that it uses key look-ups. So if this was a map of addresses to integers then it would look something like:

```
[0x000000000000000A] 555
[0x0000000000000004] 123
....
[0x0000000000000006] 22
[0x0000000000000003] 6
```

Or in code

```
mapping(address => uint) _map;

function getter(address _addr) returns(uint) {
    return _map[_addr];
}
```

So basically, you're referencing values with an object instead of an integer in short. The keys also don't have to be in sequence.

Comment: Good explanation. Also, mappings are explained here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9893/how-does-mapping-in-solidity-work
I would like to add that it is possible to have a mapping inside mapping in Solidity ;)